# splittling a file into multiple with a delimiter awk

Tags: file, awk, split

I am trying to split files evenly in a number of chunks.  This is my code:

```
awk '/*/ { delim++ } { file = sprintf("splits/audio%s.txt", int(delim /2)); print >> file; }' < input_file
```

my files looks like this:

```
"*/audio1.lab"
0 6200000 a
6200000 7600000 b
7600000 8200000 c
.
"*/audio2.lab"
0 6300000 a
6300000 8300000 w
8300000 8600000 e
8600000 10600000 d
.
```

It is giving me an error: awk: line 1: syntax error at or near *
I do not know enough about awk to understand this error.  I tried escaping characters but still haven't been able to figure it out. I could write a script in python but I would like to learn how to do this in awk.  Any awkers know what I am doing wrong?

Edit:  I have 14021 files.  I gave the first two as an example.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're trying to do. Are you trying to split files or merge files or something else? Is that sampel input one file or 2 separate files? Clarify what `I am trying to split files evenly in a number of chunks.` means and post the expected output given that sample input.

Comment: split the file by the headers.  Conveniently the header are the only lines with an "*"

Comment: So you have 1 file that looks like your posted input and you want to split it into multiple files, one per block? Or are you trying to get 2 blocks from the input file into each output file (hence the divide by 2) or something else? What does any of this have to do with you having 14021 files? Do you want unique output files for each block across all input files or some kind of merging or what? Again, a better description and posting the expected output would be a big help.

Comment: it is one per block.  I edited because David Gish's first response worked for a smaller file and his edit worked for the larger one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, your regular expression is illegal; '*' says to match the previous character 0 or more times, but there is no previous character.

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but it looks like when you encounter a line with an asterisk you want to bump the file number. To match an asterisk, you'll need to escape it:

```
awk '/\*/ { close(file); delim++ } { file = sprintf("splits/audio%d.txt", int(delim /2)); print >> file; }' < input_file
```

Also note `%d` is the correct format character for decimal output from an `int`.

Comment: you are correct david. I am trying to bump up when I find an asterisk.  I also tried as you suggested, however it gave me a different error: awk: cannot open "splits/audio1021.txt" for output (Too many open files) I have more files than two, I was trying to keep the question simple.  Is this a memory issue?

Comment: That's a lot of files. In your first clause, try something like: {close (file); delim++}

Comment: perfect!  You sir are a wizard! I did not know about the closing.  That is really good stuff.

Comment: Glad to be of help

Comment: Don't recalculate `file` for every input line, just do it once when you increment `delim`. You don't mean `>>`, you mean `>` (this is awk, not shell). Don't use input redirection with awk as it's not extensible to multiple files and robs awk of the ability to use `FILENAME`.

Comment: @Ed Morton ok I thought the ">>" would help with large files.  what do you mean about the file?

Comment: That comment was for David. Once you've edited your question to provide the necessary information I'll provide an answer that I'll be happy to answer questions on if you have any.

Answer (score 1):

idk what all the other stuff around this question is about but to just split your input file into separate output files all you need is:

```
awk '/\*/{close(out); out="splits/audio"++c".txt"} {print > out}' file
```

Since "repetition" metacharacters like `*` or `?` or `+` can take on a literal meaning when they are the first character in a regexp, the regexp `/*/` will work just fine in some (e.g. gawk) but not all awks and since you apparently have a problem with having too many files open you must not be using gawk (which manages files for you) so you probably need to escape the `*` and `close()` each output file when you're done writing to it. No harm doing that and it makes the script portable to all awks.

Comment: Much cleaner. I considered doing a rewrite, but pointing out what was broken seemed more instructive.

Comment: There's also an edge case (the perennial bane of clean code) where any contents prior to the first * is lost. To fix that, `out` should be initialized in a `BEGIN` section.

Comment: The OP doesn't have any lines before the first `*` so we don't need to handle that potential case. If that statement is wrong then the OP needs to fix his sample input/output so we can see what we're really dealing with.

Comment: True enough, just pointing out that unless we immediately encounter an asterisk, we're outputting to a nil file name. I'm not sure how finicky various awks are about that, but loose ends bug me.

Comment: awk would produce an immediate fatal error about having a null string on  the right side of output redirection.